# Accelerometer calculation

Tags: c++, qt-creator, accelerometer, raspberry-pi2, gyroscope

I cant find what is wrong here in this code. I am trying to get accelerometer data, but when i try to run it on device, that is working but not a proper reading I think problem in calculation, same logic I have used for gyro and taken proper reading but accelerometer output displayed  `Accelx :3.56023e-09  Accely :1.76423e-42  Accelz :1.77404e-42`

```
    accelX = accelerometer->Loop_Accelx();
    accelY = accelerometer->Loop_Accely();
    accelZ = accelerometer->Loop_Accelz();

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) //averaging of accelerometer data upto 3 readings
    {
        float accelX1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accelx(); //storing the Accelx value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class
        float accelY1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accely(); //storing the Accely value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class
        float accelZ1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accelz(); //storing the Accelz value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class

        accelX = accelX + accelX1;
        accelY = accelY + accelY1;
        accelZ = accelZ + accelZ1;

        delay(1);
    }

    accelX = accelX/3;
    accelY = accelY/3;
    accelZ = accelZ/3;

    if(numbercount == number){

    emit Accelx_Data(accelX);
    emit Accely_Data(accelY);
    emit Accelz_Data(accelZ);

    cout<<"Accelx :"<<accelX<<"  Accely :"<<accelY<<"  Accelz :"<<accelZ<<endl;
```

dmpmpu_demo file for accel x :

```
float DmpMPU6050_Demo::Loop_Accelx()
{
    if (!dmpReady)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    fifoCount = mpu.getFIFOCount();

    if (fifoCount == 1024)
    {
        mpu.resetFIFO();
        printf("FIFO overflow!\n");
    }

    else if (fifoCount >= 42 )
    {
        mpu.getFIFOBytes(fifoBuffer, packetSize);

        #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL

        mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
        mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
        mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
        mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);

        #endif

        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried shaking your board while running the tests? Because, you know, the Earth's revolution/rotation accelerations are too small to register values high enough on an accelerometer at rest.

Comment: Thanks adrian, Actually I have added that in my testing vehicle, So when I start the vehicle It will get shake, depends upon that the reading will display, I got gyro reading using same Ic. Problem in calculation.

Comment: I can't see any fault in the code. Do you have another board to test? b/c it's not uncommon some components to go busted - see [esd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic-sensitive_device)

Comment: Note that the first two readings are taken without a delay between them.  You need to move the call to `delay` to the front of the loop.

Comment: front of the for loop ? K i il try

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tried but I got similar ouput Accelx :7.10318e-42  Accely :5.32353e-42  Accelz :5.32353e-42 Accelx :7.14382e-42  Accely :7.14942e-42  Accelz :5.36697e-42

Comment: Hi Adrian, Ya I have tried but I got similar output. If any component busted means I can't get gyro output also, but I got gyro, sensor reading -28.628  pitch :-28.628  roll :-28.628 yaw :-57.9645  pitch :-57.9645  roll :-44.1806 yaw :-122.508  pitch :-122.508  roll :-65.4697 yaw :-134.465  pitch :-103.711  roll :-103.711

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, there's no need to shake it to sense the gravitational acceleration `g` in the Z axis.  And the three values are exactly the same magnitude.  Something wrong in the reading code I'm afraid. I'm just sit on my chair and sense it.

Comment: @JerwinPrabuA, getting the mean for three values is not a good estimate for a smoothed value.  It should be better to print all three values to se at least if there's some variation.

Comment: The only value returned by `float DmpMPU6050_Demo::Loop_Accelx()` is a `1` (as an error value it seems)...

Comment: @Bob__   indeed `Loop_Accelx()` is missing any `return` except the very first `if (!dmpReady)`,

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that should result in UB and a possible reason for the values obtained (something e-42 are denormal values for 32bit `float`s, probably random bits).

Comment: `accelX = accelX/ 0.16384;
        accelY = accelY/ 0.16384;
        accelZ = accelZ/ 0.16384;` If I changed calculation like this I got out put, but ouput value                                                                                                           Accelx :12.207  Accely :6.10352  Accelz :6.10352                          Accelx :4.94433e-05  Accely :4.94433e-05  Accelz :3.29622e-05                                              
Accelx :12.207  Accely :1.30953e-40  Accelz :1.31013e-40
Accelx :18.3105  Accely :6.10352  Accelz :6.10352

Comment: @JerwinPrabuA do you realize thst you don't have a proper `return` with a float value from the `float DmpMPU6050_Demo::Loop_Accelx()`? Count how many `return` statements you see there.

Comment: @JerwinPrabuA Suggestion: change your DmpMPU6050 library. E.g. have a look on [this one][MPU6050-Pi-Demo].

Comment: @ Adrian I already saw that, depends upon that demo file, I have created this code, I think it is similar.

Comment: @JerwinPrabuA "I think it is similar." No matter what you think, the current code is buggy. Would you mind to post the functions for the gyro reading? Or upload the entire DmpMPU6050_Demo h/cpp files somewhere. BTW, sorry for the broken link, [here it is again](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/MPU6050-Pi-Demo)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi As per your suggestion in dmpmpu_demo file I have added `return 1;` above `#endif` I go the ouput like `yaw :-6.17357  pitch :-6.17357  roll :-6.17357 Accelx :18.3106  Accely :12.2071  Accelz :18.3105 yaw :-9.05116  pitch :-14.7817  roll :-14.7817
Accelx :6.10371  Accely :12.2072  Accelz :12.2072` but I got confused whether the reading is correct or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must sense the gravitational acceleration of the earth**.  This means that the vertical component of the vector you get must be clearly defined, and you get a vector that is clearly the zero vector.  This is wrong and indicates you are not getting correct values from the accelerometer.  Check that.

Next time, it will be better to post complete code, as the global `accelX`, `accelY` and `accelZ` declarations are not seen anywhere in your code, what can be the actual source of problems... We don't have also the definitions of `accelerometer->LoopAccel...()` prototypes.

And finally, *don't shake it to sense data* as has been told in the comments.  Accelerometers sense the gravitational attraction of the earth, and you can just change its orientation to see a change in the acceleration vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I have posted my source code only, I will take the signals from header and connected to source slot. In public variable `DmpMPU6050_Demo *accelerometer;` in header. I will include the dmp, you can check. If possible give example calculation using this code.

Comment: For my calculation purpose I have added `accelx1`

Comment: `accelX = accelX/ 0.16384; accelY = accelY/ 0.16384; accelZ = accelZ/ 0.16384;` If I changed calculation like this I got out put, but ouput value `Accelx :12.207 Accely :6.10352 Accelz :6.10352 Accelx :4.94433e-05 Accely :4.94433e-05 Accelz :3.29622e-05 Accelx :12.207 Accely :1.30953e-40 Accelz :1.31013e-40 Accelx :18.3105 Accely :6.10352 Accelz :6.10352`

Comment: @Bob__, Oooops! that's true!  My apologies for that!  you're right.

Answer (score 0):

In dmpmpu.cpp file I have added return

```
    #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_REALACCEL

    mpu.dmpGetQuaternion(&q, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetAccel(&aa, fifoBuffer);
    mpu.dmpGetGravity(&gravity, &q);
    mpu.dmpGetLinearAccel(&aaReal, &aa, &gravity);

    return 3;
    #endif

    printf("\n");
```

For calculating the Accelero value without number count

```
        accelX = accelerometer->Loop_Accelx();
    accelY = accelerometer->Loop_Accely();
    accelZ = accelerometer->Loop_Accelz();

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) //averaging of accelerometer data upto 3 readings
    {
        float accelX1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accelx(); //storing the Accelx value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class
        float accelY1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accely(); //storing the Accely value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class
        float accelZ1 = accelerometer->Loop_Accelz(); //storing the Accelz value from DmpMPU6050_Demo class

        accelX = accelX + accelX1;
        accelY = accelY + accelY1;
        accelZ = accelZ + accelZ1;

        delay(1);
    }

    accelX = accelX/ 0.16384;
    accelY = accelY/ 0.16384;
    accelZ = accelZ/ 0.16384;
```

Finally I got the output like

```
yaw :8.3854  pitch :8.3854  roll :8.3854
Accelx :54.9316  Accely :54.9316  Accelz :54.9316
yaw :-5.5964  pitch :-5.5964  roll :-5.5964
Accelx :42.7246  Accely :36.6211  Accelz :30.5176
yaw :-129.255  pitch :-129.255  roll :-91.2928
Accelx :36.6214  Accely :48.8281  Accelz :30.5176
```